# Could not load template error in opencart Version 2.1.0.2

Tags: php, opencart2.x, vqmod

I am getting following error after refreshing modification and I don't have file `footertop.tpl` at that location.

url - [Website Link](https://www.dreamkarts.com/)

> Notice: Error: Could not load template
>   /home/dreamkarts/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/footertop.tpl!
>   in
>   /home/dreamkarts/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_system_engine_loader.php
>   on line 86

Comment: you are getting this error due to footertop.tpl file is missing in the theme folder. You will have to add footertop.tpl file at location catalog/view/theme/your theme/template/common/footertop.tpl

Comment: and what will be the code inside that file

Comment: Before refreshing modification everything was going perfect but once I have refreshed modification this error occurred.

Comment: Have you installed any extension? If you have installed custom theme contact 3rd party developer.

Comment: yes I have installed a theme.

Comment: I would suggest contacting 3rd party theme developer.

Comment: @RakeshMishra have you default theme selected from admin now?

Answer (score 0):

default template doesn't contains footertop.tpl, it was some module is calling, check for module / plugin zip, if that contains that footoptop.tpl